# Getting a CORS error in a POST request even without a preflight request being issued

Tags: angular, google-chrome, http, cors

I actually do know how to solve this with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. But I'm curious as to why is this happening, because there is no OPTIONS preflight being sent on Chrome's Network tab (also checked in Firefox). I can even see the full response on the network tab... So here is the request/response information:

**General**:

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/test/api/login

Request Method:POST

Status Code:200 OK

Remote Address:[::1]:8080

Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Request Headers**:

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*

Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9

Cache-Control:no-cache

Connection:keep-alive

Content-Length:37

content-type:text/plain

Host:localhost:8080

Origin:http://localhost:8100

Pragma:no-cache

Referer:http://localhost:8100/

User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36

**Response Headers**:

Content-Length:12

Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8

Date:Wed, 07 Mar 2018 21:32:52 GMT

Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

**Error message (Chrome's console)**:

Failed to load http://localhost:8080/po27/api/login: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

Don't think it matters but: the request is being made with Angular 4's HttpService

Answer (score 1):

POST's don't require a preflight in and of themselves. In your case, since you're doing a POST with 'standard' request headers, the browser won't add a preflight OPTIONS request.

That being said, as you obviously understand, without adding the CORS response headers to your POST response, you're going to be blocked.